# Desktop will not load. 14.04. problem with libstdc++.so.6

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, files

I'm new to the forum. Have little experience with Ubuntu.

I needed to install an epson scanner and a scanner program. I managed to make the scanner program xsane and iscan work. These did not suffice for the work I have so I bought Vuescan in order the do my work on this platform. (I'm going to scan a lot of slides).

Vuescan did not work immediately. It reported some problems with the libstdc++.so.6 (.21 and .20 versions?)

I tried to fix the problems using first the desktop installer system. This was not possible. I kept getting errors and were not able to get a long this way.

I reverted to terminal and used apt-get different ways tracing solutions I found on the net.

Then I happened to install *wrong version of the libstdc++ (for amd64)* in place of the intel version i need. My mistake.

I tried different things to remove and reinstall the old version. Latest I have copied the ubuntu 14.04 intel versions of the libstdc++.so.6 and -.so.5 files into the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. Library.

What I see when I boot is:
ubuntu fails to start the desktop. It reaches the login prompt and tries to start the desktop but reverts to the login prompt.
I can start a terminal on ctrl alt f4. This gives some error messages.
If I try to start apt-get I get similar errors:
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6 invalid ELF header.

What can I do to locate the problem. What can I do to make the desktop to start. It keeps reverting to the login prompt.

Comment: Yes. I cannot use apt-get because it just gives me the message: apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6 invalid ELF header.

Comment: Exactly what does: "Invalid ELF header" imply?

Answer (score 1):

In such case you need to download `libstdc++6` package manually and install it:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4_i386.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4_amd64.deb
```

Then continue as usual

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: As noted in my question, it is an intel 64 bit machine. My fault was that I used an advice similar to the advice you give here, and this way made my problem escalate. ;o) I have tried to download and install the intel versions of libstdc++6, but the problem is that I cannot use apt-get. (As I have noted above).

Comment: I guess the amd64 version does not fit with the intel64?

Comment: Yes, but isn't it two different architectures and instruction sets?

Comment: How can I make apt-get work?

Comment: Ok. When I try: "sudo dpkg -i --force-all libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4_amd64.deb" I get: Could not be configured because libstdc++6:i386 is an other version (5.4.0-ubuntu1~16.04.9).

Comment: Try to install for both architectures (see update above).

Comment: The trick that made it work was to follow your first instruction and then remove the i386 related files from the system. Now I can boot into the window manager again. Thank you. I used wget to download the package and dpkg to install. Then manually removed the i386 related files. This made the login prompt function properly again.

Comment: Then using the apt-get procedure made things up to date. Later I realized that recent version of vuescan uses a version of the gcc++ not supported by ubuntu 14.04. I downgraded to a previous version (from 9.6.06 down to version 9.4.67) This removed all my problems.