# Error trying to import librosa in python3: symbol _ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6

Tags: python, gcc

I've spent all day searching for solutions to this problem. At first it was an GLIBCXX_1.9 problem, I've tried to use solutions in here (install a gcc newest version and others solutions), and it became a GLIBCXX_1.8 problem, tried another solutions, and now is this:

---

```
>>> import librosa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/data-hunter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import decompose
  File "/home/data-hunter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/decompose.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import segment
  File "/home/data-hunter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librosa/segment.py", line 33, in <module>
    import sklearn.cluster
  File "/home/data-hunter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .hierarchical import (ward_tree, AgglomerativeClustering, linkage_tree,
  File "/home/data-hunter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/hierarchical.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import _hierarchical
  File "sklearn/utils/fast_dict.pxd", line 20, in init sklearn.cluster._hierarchical
ImportError: /home/data-hunter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fast_dict.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

---

I've installed librosa by pip install, and it is v0.6.1.
My gcc and g++ are version 4.8

Comment: PS: My ubuntu is 14.04 (Trusty)

Comment: I've screwed up even more now, i just removed libstdc++.so.6 and i cant do anything, not even use apt-get. Please someone help

Comment: The main recommendation - do not use Windows-way Anaconda on Ubuntu. Use standard Ubuntu packages, or pip3. About broken libstdc see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011391/66509).